# How to get most nested values?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nested, key-value

I got a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {"my momma" : {"your momma" : 1}, "flying on" : {"a broom" : 2}}
```

I need to multiply all most nested values (the 1 and the 2) by 2.

How do I do this?
I just cant manage to access them.

Comment: Where is your code and what precisely is the problem with it? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I got no code. I tried to catch the values with an for loop but that just didnt work.

Comment: It sounds very much like you *do* have code then. Is a `for` loop somehow *not* code? Show some effort!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to do something after multiplying. This is the start of my function so there is litterly only one line (def multiply():) so...

Comment: Well step one would be write more than one line. This isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. You were lucky to get an answer this time, but for the future learn [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe not like I didnt try everything I could think of. But without this part I couldnt move on, so what should I do beside asking?

Comment: It's OK to ask, but if you've tried everything you could think of then **show that in the question**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for key in d:
    for skey in d[key]:
        d[key][skey] *= 2
print d
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion, if you don't know how many nesting levels you will have:

```
INDEX = []

def disMantle(target, depth):
    # ensure a list for given depth
    while len(INDEX) <= depth: INDEX.append([])
    # analyze given target
    for key in target:
        atype = type(target[key])

        if atype == dict:
            # next depth
            disMantle(target[key], depth+1)
        elif atype in [int,float]:
            # record the numeric values
            INDEX[depth].append({'key':key,'value':target[key]})

d = {"my momma" : {"your momma" : 1}, "flying on" : {"a broom" : 2.0}}

disMantle(d, 0)
print INDEX[-1]
```